# Get JSON Data From Text using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE
   @LeadID INT,
   @CompanyID INT,
   @Text VARCHAR(MAX) = ''


 (
 SELECT TOP 1 @Text = CAST(JsonData AS VARCHAR(MAX))
 FROM XeroLog 
 WHERE 
    CompanyID = @CompanyID AND 
    InvoiceID = '' AND 
    IsDeleted = 0 AND 
    JsonData IS NOT NULL
 )

 SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @Text, 
    CHARINDEX('{', @Text), 
    CHARINDEX(']  }', @text) - CHARINDEX('{', @Text) + Len(']  }')
 )
```

I am trying to retrieve JsonData from text I am using above query to retrieve data but I got this error message

> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

How to rectify this problem?

Comment: Pass the correct values to your substring function?

Comment: What is the actual value of `@Text`, what is the expected result and what is the SQL Server version? Thanks.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)